Black specks in hot water, brand new house
I moved into a brand new house 4 months ago. I am still getting black specks in hot water. It’s in shower area of all the bathrooms. All are PEX pipes and don’t see any flexible hoses anywhere. I have attached images for reference. Builder sent these to the plumber but he is not able to figure out. I have Navien’s tankless water heater and expansion tank.




all those elbows and tees are black... Have you tested the incoming water at the stop tap?

By your statement, the house is new.  How much time have you allowed for debris to be flushed out of the system?

I moved in May, it’s been 4 months we have been using hotter and issue is since day 1

@Lucky Roy,  I added that info to your question.

What is your water source? If there is high iron and/or manganese level, they may precipitate out on heating. Test if the specks slowly dissolve or change color in a reducing agent, such as Red-B-Gone, https://red-b-gone.com or have a local agricultural station or school check them. If that is the issue, you might need a water softener.

Issue is not related to magnesium or iron levels. They are black plasticky particles.
